# Cropping a bitmap gives an empty bitmap

Tags: c#, image, graphics, image-processing, crop

I've taken a code from here (SO) that crops images. I tried it on bitmaps containing black text on white font. The result i get in return is a completely white output with no content.

```
        // create new bitmap with desired size and same pixel format
        Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        // create Graphics "wrapper" to draw into our new bitmap
        // "using" guarantees a call to gfx.Dispose()
        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBitmap))
        {
            // draw the wanted part of the original bitmap into the new bitmap
            gfx.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        return croppedBitmap;
```

Any guess?

**PS** if i crop in paint of course it does work

**edit**

If I crop a picture of me for example it works....

**Appendix**

Code:

**Rectangles**:

```
        Rectangle 1: 8 50, 95, 80, 30 // invoice number
        Rectangle 2: 625, 778, 475, 22 // Total amount
```

**CropImage():**

```
    public static Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle rect)
    {
        Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBitmap))
        {
            gfx.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        return croppedBitmap;
    }
```

Image:
(Sensitive data is hidden, I only left the part I'm trying to crop)
http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/5703/modelx.png

Comment: did you debug the program and check that all the variables in the code hold the correct data? this might seem like a wrong-path issue or something of the sort IMHO

Comment: Yes I did that my variables are good

Comment: post link of question from where you have taken code.

Comment: What is the value of the rect??

Comment: @Javed: I've read the whole and there's nothing relevant in there other than the code. @Aliostad: Don't worry about rect it's set to the correct value.

Comment: Can you send us a link of image you are trying to crop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(625, 778, 475, 22);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\m.png") as Bitmap;

    Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    croppedBitmap.SetResolution(bitmap.HorizontalResolution, bitmap.VerticalResolution);

    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBitmap))
    {
        gfx.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    croppedBitmap.Save(@"C:\m-1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Habjan now I understand it looks like the resolution wasn't the same, I measured the target parts in Paint and it's still giving wrong spots for the rectangles you see above... for example, for the invoice number I can see the whole number but also the bottom border and some text, which means the rectangle is taking a bigger frame. But in another hand, the total frame seem to take a blank area not even the amount area which is weird too.. any guess?

Comment: I made 2 changes, Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, rect.Width, rect.Height);  and croppedBitmap.SetResolution(bitmap.HorizontalResolution, bitmap.VerticalResolution);

Comment: maaaan... i didn't see the 2nd change ! You rock my world mate ! it works like a charm ! I seriously dunno how to say thanks but THANK YOU !